# How do I run this shell script?

Tags: shell, cakephp

I'm using this script:
https://github.com/gilleswittenberg/BackupSql/blob/master/BackupSqlShell.php

But when I run cake BackupSql from my terminal within my console folder I get this error:
Error: Shell class BackupSqlShell could not be found.

I have put BackupSqlShell.php inside app/Console/Command/

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

You should run shells in 2.x as follows (from the app dir):

```
Console/cake FooBar
```

You can run `Console/cake` which will output what is available. Try it and see if your shell is showing.

If it is, make sure you type it correctly, copy paste to be sure.

If its not, check permissions and location is 100% correct, eg: case and so on.

**Edit:** You can not, ever, run shells from Console/Command. always from APP dir.